# Repair a new light fixture

Tags: lighting

I have a new light fixture with a ring that goes on a ceramic socket that secures a glass shade. A socket wrench was included to screw the ring on the socket. It is impossible to unscrew the ring from the socket even with the socket wrench. Can I replace the ceramic socket and rings so there will be a socket where the rings can easily be screwed and unscrewed?

Comment: Could you add a picture? I think I know what you're talking about but a picture would help.

Comment: If it is new you probably return it and get a light fixture that better fits your wants.  Once you change it, it is yours with no warranty.